# Does select_for_update() work if AUTOCOMMIT is set to False in Django Rest-Framework

Tags: mysql, django, django-rest-framework, concurrency

I am writing a celery task which would get invoked if a row is being inserted into a table. This task is being executed in a transaction and the task also locks the certain rows of several tables.

Now lets assume this task is being executed when `AUTOCOMMIT` & `ATOMIC_REQUESTS` is enabled.

This is how it looks like -

```
@app.task
@transaction.atomic
def celery_task(a, b):

   result = Orders.objects.filter(filed = "Value")

   # here the result might have 10 of records but I just need few of them based on a very 
   # specific business logic.
   
   # so I pick those which are required and should be locked.
   
   rows_to_lock = [result[0], result[1]] # has only ids of the rows in this list
   
   # Now to put on the records which are in - rows_to_lock

   result = Orders.objects.select_for_update().filter(id__in=rows_to_lock)

   ...
   ...
```

Now when this celery task is being invoked twice with two different arguments and at the same time and if the resultant rows of orders are exactly same then I have noticed that the locks to update the records aren't working.

1. Does the decorator `@transaction.atomic` works with the current database configurations that I have?
2. Will I be able to solve the issue if I set the `AUTOCOMMIT` as `False`?
3. Also will I be able to use the decorator `@transaction.atomic` if `AUTOCOMMIT` is set as `False`?
4. Do I have to make any changes to the transactions if I set `AUTOCOMMIT` as `False`?
5. Does `select_for_update()` support the current database configurations I have?

Here is the actual task.

```
def get_buy_order_matching_queryset(order_obj):
    """
    This will return the query to get the list of buy or sell orders depending upon order_obj.
    """
    from orders.models import Orders, OrderStatus
    from properties.models import PropertyOwners

    order_type = order_obj.order_type.name
    order_units = order_obj.units

    if order_type == BUY:

        order_price = order_obj.buy_price_per_unit
        created_by = order_obj.created_by.id

        # this query will be returned only if the order_type is BUY
        queryset = (
            Orders.objects.exclude(created_by__id=created_by, is_market_order=True)
                .filter(
                property=order_obj.property,
                order_type__name=SELL,
                order_status__in=[PARTIALLY_COMPLETED[1], OPEN[1]],
                sell_price_per_unit__lte=order_price,
            )
                .order_by("sell_price_per_unit", "created_at")
        )

        if queryset.exists():

            # total units from fetched sell orders.
            current_units = 0

            # list of sale orders to be considered for locking and for trades.
            orders = []

            for order in queryset:
                current_units = current_units + (order.units - order.sold_units)
                orders.append(order.id)
                if current_units > order_units:
                    break
            # locking the orders which are required.
            queryset = Orders.objects.select_for_update().values(
                "id",
                "property",
                "units",
                "created_by",
                "sell_price_per_unit",
                "order_trade_fee",
                "tax_percent",
                "order_status",
            ).filter(id__in=orders).order_by("sell_price_per_unit", "created_at")

            # this loop is to iterate over query set.
            for order in queryset:

                # lock the property_owners of the sell orders.
                logger.info(
                    "Lock the property owners of the selected sell orders.")
                property_owner = PropertyOwners.objects.select_for_update().get(
                    property=order["property"], owner=order["created_by"]
                )

                # identifying if it is a partially completed order.
                if order["order_status"] == PARTIALLY_COMPLETED[1]:
                    # get the sold units if the order is partially completed.
                    order_sold_units = get_sell_order_units(order["id"])

                    # update the units of orders by subtracting the sold units. And now the order['units'] will have
                    # the units which are not sold.
                    total_order_units = order["units"]
                    sold_units = sum(
                        [order.units for order in order_sold_units])

                    order["units"] = total_order_units - sold_units
        else:

            if order_obj.is_market_order:
                logger.info(
                    "No matching order found for the market order. Hence, moving it to the cancelled state."
                )

                order_obj.order_status = OrderStatus.objects.get(
                    pk=CANCELLED[1])
                order_obj.save()

    return {
        "order_id": order_obj.id,  # this is the buyer's order_id
        "order_type": order_type,  # this is the order_type
        "order_price": order_price,  # this is the buyer's order's per-unit price
        "order_units": order_units,  # this is the buyer's order's units
        "created_by": created_by,  # this is the buyer
        "trade_fee": order_obj.order_trade_fee,
        "order_tax": order_obj.tax_percent,
        "matched_results": list(
            queryset
        ),  # this is the list of sell orders from whom this buyer can buy.
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the rest of your task where you use the `result` query? The lock will only be applied when the query is evaluated

Comment: I have updated the question to show the method being invoked within that task.

Comment: In my actual code the `result` is `queryset`